# Macro Variable of VStudio in TeamCity not set

Tags: visual-studio, macros, teamcity

I have to use a Pre-Build event in Visual Studio in order to either copy a file from template version to compilable version, or to call a tool to translate the file - depending if I am in Debug or in Release mode.
As found here before, I used the debug switch

```
if $(ConfigurationName) == Debug goto :debug

$(SolutionDir)\Tools\MyTool\Translate -i $(ProjectDir)\Themes\Generic.Template.xaml -o $(ProjectDir)\Themes\Generic.xaml 

goto :end

:debug

copy /y $(ProjectDir)\Themes\Generic.Template.xaml $(ProjectDir)\Themes\Generic.xaml

:end
```

Everything works fine, as long as I use my local Visual Studio. But when building with TeamCity, the Studio macro variables are not set correctly. Visual Studio itself is not installed on the build server. As build script we use f#make, which calls msbuild with the solution file. Calling the build batch locally also runs perfectly, so it seems that TeamCity hides these vars somehow.

Are there any known issues about that?

Answer (score 0):

I do know that there are distinct differences between msbuild and devenv.exe when building against a .sln file.  For example, msbuild driven builds will not build Visual Studio deployment projects.  I can't say for sure what the effects are within prebuild steps.

I recommend changing your TeamCity build step to use devenv.exe instead of msbuild (probably will need a command line build step) and just see if it works better.

TeamCity provides some built  build parameters that can help you find the correct path to devenv.exe on your agent(s).  They are env.VS100COMNTOOLS and VS2010_Path.

Comment: I use $(ProjectDir)\.. instead, and try to get rid of DevStudio macros :/